# Custom Hooks are not visible in the back-office of PrestaShop

Tags: php, html, hook, prestashop

I've created a module in PrestaShop and registered it to a custom Hook:

```
public function install()
{
  if (Shop::isFeatureActive())
    Shop::setContext(Shop::CONTEXT_ALL);

  return parent::install() &&
    $this->registerHook('homeProducts') &&
    $this->registerHook('header') &&
    Configuration::updateValue('MYMODULE_NAME', 'my friend');
}
```

[...]

```
public function hookDisplayHomeProducts($params)
{
  $this->context->smarty->assign(
      array(
          'my_module_name' => Configuration::get('MYMODULE_NAME'),
          'my_module_link' => $this->context->link->getModuleLink('mymodule', 'display')
      )
  );
  return $this->display(__FILE__, 'mymodule.tpl');
}
```

This module works fine with a native hook (for example `displayLeftColumn`) but when I create a custom one (like "`homeProducts`") then I am unable to transplant my module to that hook, because it's not visible on the list of hooks.

**How can I make this custom hook appear in the list of available hooks?**

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem come from your hook name and the associated function.

What if you call the hook with the 'display' prefix:

`$this->registerHook('displayHomeProducts')`,

then Prestashop will find the associated function hookDisplayHomeProducts, and you will be ok.

Right now, prestashop search for hookHomeProducts which doesn't exists.

Answer (score 0):

Open the table **ps_hook** in your databes, and set **live_edit = 1**